# How to write a function to change the color of text and background as well as change the text of p by clicking only one button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, function, if-statement

Screenshot Menu of Homepage including the "Plain"-Button to make the page more accessible

[image]

I am just programming my first website and I wish to have two versions of it. One complex and one plain/ accessible following the guidelines of accessibility.

This means I need to change from version 1 to version 2:

- a) the language/ content (hence I need to access p, h1, h2 of the different sections)
- b) the style (background color of all sections, color of all sections etc.).

My idea was to use a button with a Click-Event function for this and then use:

- a) innerText to change the content
- b) addClasslist to create a classlist that has the characteristics (color etc.) that I want to change.

My first try was this:

**HTML of the Nav**

```
<body class="complex">
  <header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">

<div class="topnav">
        <div class="languages">
        <a href="./Spanish/index.html" class="active">ES</a>
        <a href="./German/index.html" class="active">DE</a>
        <button class="accessible"><span class="easy"></span>Plain</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Navigation links (hidden by default) -->
        <div id="myLinks">
          <a href="#work">Projects</a>
          <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
        </div>

        <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"> <span class="menu"> Menu </span> </i>
        </a>
      </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const accessible = document.querySelector (".accessible");
const body = document.querySelector("complex");

accessible.addEventListener('click', () => body.classList.add('add-accessibility'));
```

How to access innerText here?

**CSS of the new classlist for the body (.complex)**

```
.add-accessibility {
    color: #2b2c2c;
    background-color: #eae4dd;
}
```

This is totally not working at all until now. The classlist is not added to the body the way I have written the function when I click the button.

Do you have ideas how to write a working function for all this changes needed in content and style? And do you know what the error in my idea above is? why does it not even add the classlist?

My other idea was to use a function with if/else. If this might be a better choice I am also glad to hear your ideas.

Another option could be to create a second css styles document and change to it by clicking the button but then I still do not know how to access the innerText, if my function above does not work.

Comment: Just to start, try debugging eg by console.log of things. I see that the querySelector to get body element is lacking a dot before the complex for example which you would see if trying to console.log the result.

Comment: I don't see a lot of ReactJS in this question, Sarah. Is there a reason you tagged it?

Comment: As @A Haworth said you are missing a dot in the class complex when using querySelector: const body = document.querySelector(".complex");

Comment: Also check if you properly linked you css style sheet and script to your HTML file

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i did add the dot before complex and debugged and it did not make the function work. Also my css style and the html are conntected,well, so unfortunately this function still seems to have a general problem in how it is written. Do you have any idea? And I added React as my function (which is not working) is a React Function and I would like to use another to access the innerText and do not know how to write that one. But as I said, if anyone thinks that a JavaScript if/else statement is more useful and knows how it would be written I am glad, too. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest checking out [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would help you get a better response to your question. As it stands, I can not reproduce your issues with the given information. If all you're looking for is a demo on how to change text content and stylings with a button press, that is something I can help with :)

Comment: Maybe reading up about accessibility might be a good place to start e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example of how to use `document.querySelector`, and event listener, and `innerText` I made the small example below.

First I define the variables I intend to use, the button that is going to trigger a change. I grab it using a query selector similar to how css grabs things, the name of the html element `button` and touching the tag name is the class with a period proceeding resulting in `button.change`.

I add an event listener to the button element defined, and specify that I'm waiting for a click. Then I pass an anonymous arrow function as the code to be executed whenever I click the button.

I first toggle the class `"accessible-styles"` which will change the display of my page. Then, I check to see if the page is currently accessible. The result of `.contains` method will return a `bool`; `true` if it is contained, and `false` if it is not. Then I can use a conditional statement.

My conditional statement says `if(isAccessible)` which means if the result of the `.contains` method is `true` it will run that block of code. The else keyword following specifies what will happen if the result is `false`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button.change");
const textField = document.querySelector(".changing-text");
const body = document.querySelector("body");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  body.classList.toggle("accessible-styles");
  const isAccessible = body.classList.contains("accessible-styles");
  if (isAccessible) {
    textField.innerText = "Accessible Styles!";
  } else {
    textField.innerText = "Base Styles!";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: hotpink;
}

.accessible-styles {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="changing-text">
  Base Styles!
</div>
<button class="change">Change Things</button>
```

However there may be other better ways to accomplish your goals. Things like [prefers-contrast media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-contrast) come to mind. Also you can change the text content with css alone using `display: none` on a span element that is a child of specific tags if you go a media query route.

Good semantic html is more powerful than most stylistic changes though- if someone has a screen reader that will help the layout make more sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! The example was very helpful and also the ideas about "how to create an MRE" and the media query. I will investigate and try out all of it. And thanks a lot for the comment on how ereaders can do the job with stylistic changes. Also thanks for the new, great ressources about accessibility! have a great day